# Core UI: Menu Missing in Mobile Browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, core-ui

Why is the menu missing in the CoreUI template in mobile or smaller browsers?
This is what it looks like in bigger browsers.

[image]

But in smaller browsers, it displays like this and there is no way to see the sidebar menu.

[image]

Here is the HTML code.

```
<header class="c-header c-header-light c-header-fixed c-header-with-subheader">
        <button class="c-header-toggler c-class-toggler mfs-3 d-md-down-none" type="button" data-target="#sidebar"
            data-class="c-sidebar-lg-show" responsive="true">
            <svg class="c-icon c-icon-lg">
                <use xlink:href="http://scheduling.test/template/vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-menu"></use>
            </svg>
        </button>
        <ul class="c-header-nav d-md-down-none">
            <h2 style="display: block">Bird System System</h2>

        </ul>


        <ul class="c-header-nav ml-auto mr-4">

            <li class="c-header-nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="c-header-nav-link" data-coreui-toggle="dropdown" href="http://scheduling.test/teacher/notification"
                    role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <svg class="c-icon mr-2">
                        <use xlink:href="http://scheduling.test/template/vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-bell"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="badge rounded-pill position-absolute top-0 end-0 badge-danger"
                        id="span_notification"></span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="c-header-nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="c-header-nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                    admin@admin.com
                </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right pt-0">
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://scheduling.test/users">
                        <svg class="c-icon mr-2">
                            <use xlink:href="http://scheduling.test/template/vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-user">
                            </use>
                        </svg> User Accounts
                    </a>
                                            <form method="POST" action="http://scheduling.test/logout">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="sOz0slBYiv6G7ezkfeuBEPcaIWzduRLRUAYWuoC5">
                        <button class="btn btn-link ropdown-item" onclick="alert('test');event.preventDefault();
                                            this.closest('form').submit();">
                            <svg class="c-icon mr-2">
                                <use
                                    xlink:href="http://scheduling.test/template/vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-account-logout">
                                </use>
                            </svg>
                            Log out
                        </button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change this

```
<button class="c-header-toggler c-class-toggler mfs-3 d-md-down-none" type="button" data-target="#sidebar"
```

to this

```
<button class="c-header-toggler c-class-toggler mfs-3" type="button" data-target="#sidebar"
```